# How do I bend a Model with an Armature? (Worm, Caterpillar, Tentacle...)

Tags: armature

I have created a model and added armature to it. I want to bend the center mesh in <kbd>^</kbd> shape. I tried to solve this with weight painting but it didn't work as expected. Is there a way to bend the model, so it looks like a walking caterpillar?

Any suggestions or help? Thanks.

[image: model and armature]

[image: bending with weight painting]

Comment: Please show the attempted bend in a still image to improve clarity.  The bend is currently shown very briefly.  The current situation makes it difficult to see for comparison purposes.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger i can pull up the bones so that it can bend. Any suggestion.

Comment: Please show the vertex density in edit mode.   Please give a internet link to a video that show the caterpillar movement you want. Are you trying for playful bone animation or high realism bone animation?

Comment: Is this a toy in two parts that hinges in the middle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it will fit your need because it looks like your object is stiff and my solution is rather for a flexible caterpillar/tentacle kind of object. Anyway here is a solution with the ***Spline IK*** constraint. Contrary to other methods, you can easily stretch and twist your object in all the directions. Nota Bene: You should use several layers to make it easier to prepare:

- Create a 5 bone armature (2 short, 2 long, one short), the first one will be the root, make the 4 other bones as long as the mesh.

[image]

- Disable the *Deform* option of the root bone, it won't have any weight on the mesh.

[image]

- Create a curve as long as the 4 front bones, subdivide it and make the vertices overlay the bones head.

[image]

- Give the front bone a *Spline IK* constraint, choose the curve as *Target*, give it a *Chain Length* of 4.

[image]

- As you can see, your curve vertices now control the bones head.

[image]

- Switch your armature to *Pose* mode, select the root bone, then select the curve, shift select the bone, and parent with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*.

[image]

- Now to make the control much easier and to be able to come back to a basic rest pose, you're going to create a second armature that will control the curve vertices: First create a bone for each head.

[image]

- Switch this new armature to *Pose* mode, select a bone, now shift select the curve, go in *Edit* mode, select the corresponding vertices, and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook To Selected Object Bone*. Same for all the other bones.

[image]

- Now as you can see, the new armature control the curve vertices.

[image]

- Switch the first armature to *Pose* mode, select the root bone, then select the second armature, select again the root bone and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*. Now when you'll move the first armature it will move the whole thing.

[image]

- Change the display of the first armature from *Octohedral* to *B-Bone*, Segment the 4 front bones (2 or 3 segments) to have a more flexible armature. Don't do it if you want to keep a stiff object.

[image]

- Parent the mesh to the first armature with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *With Automatic Weight*.

[image]

- Make sure that the *Armature* modifier is above the *Subsurf*. Enable the *Preserve Volume* option.

[image]

- It should work.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Would emphasize the automatic weights, perhaps with an image showing result.

Comment: you mean an image of the mesh in weight paint mode?

Comment: Yep.   the weight painting in the OP is poor, hence the result. It also appears the `piller in q is maybe a toy that hinges in middle.

Comment: oh you're right, I missed it was a solid stiff object  :/

Comment: Not totally sure, have asked for clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is supposed to bend with this kind of hinge though...

Comment: You could just hook the curve vertices to make handles, rather than bothering with a second armature? (You could even weight the hook influences)

Comment: the problem with simple empty hooks is that you can't reset to a rest position, but maybe I don't get what you mean?

Comment: No, you did get it, and you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion

- For playful low realism consider a lattice modifier. You may also you can consider a wave modifier.
- Less Likely. Consider shape keys to create a depression to anticipate the bend.  Skinny limbs show less issues.  Plump limbs show more issues.  This is only in regard to extreme spine positions.
- Archive your current file.
- Create a new armature with many more bones to have more flexibility.  Make sure your vertex density is high enough for you artistic purposes.
- Consider the back and front of the caterpillar as similar to the left and right human arms. (or Butterly Wings ) The human arms situation requires <<2>> sequences of bones plus a parent bone in the middle.  Your situation will probably require that as well.
- The caterpillar movement is subtle in my sample video.  You may need to consider an armature with envelope weight.
- Search on BSE for caterpillar or similar ... I think there exist discussions on similar topics.

Comment: can you plz shave with a basic shape and make it bend and let walk like caterpillar. Thanks

Comment: Oh no ... a negative vote ! ‍♂️

Comment: @atek I did not understand completely what you wrote in the comment.  I have not seen any improvements to your question.  I may or may not see improvements to question.  I am not providing a tutorial.  We do not seem to understand each other.  We may be on different time schedules.  Good Luck.