# How to bend an IK without having to go back to an FK to do the manipulation?

Tags: animation, rigging

So i'm animating a snail, and i would like to bend the tail to make a curve that goes from the body to the end of the tail. When i'm using the IK controller the tail will end where i want it to be but the curve is vertical, which i dont want it to be. My pole wont do much because the rotation is already fine. I could remove the IK and do it with an FK, but i would like to know if it was possible to get around the problem while keeping the IK?[image]

Comment: I have made an answer for a caterpillar, I don't know if it would help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135272/how-do-i-bend-a-model-with-an-armature/135286#135286