# Wondering how to go about rigging my monarch caterpillar

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify, soft-body, bone.constraints

I am guessing I want to use B-bones. So many resources, but couldn't find a good reference and this is my first rigging experience in Blender. Walk cycle: Supposedly caterpillars start with their guts(?)-the upper portion of the body before the lower/legs. Observed a pulling individual motion w/ the 3 sets of front (true) legs, followed by stretching to cause the last set of fake(prolegs) to move forward in unison, and then the other sets of prolegs in reverse order back to front. Not a hopping motion. Front legs seem to have individual strides, while prolegs seem to move in paired unison.

[image]

Comment: Maybe try the Spline IK: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135272/how-do-i-bend-a-model-with-an-armature-worm-caterpillar-tentacle

Comment: Thank you @moonboots. I’ll take a look at that. Also reading over the blender 3.4 manual for Animation and Rigging. I think the hook sounds like something that may help, assuming it does what I am guessing. Guessing it will let me attach middle section of body to end so that I can create a squash and stretch motion that helps connect to last set of fake legs. Then continue with a reverse pulling order movement of the rest of the fake legs.

Comment: I made this tuto by the way, if it helps (but it's in french):  https://youtu.be/aRdw6SoNTLM